# Cocos2dx scene in child window

Tags: cocos2d-x

The application I am writing is not a game, but does require many of the features one would use in a game... displaying a 2D scene, moving the camera to pan and zoom, rotating or otherwise animating objects within the scene. But the display of the scene will be controlled via numerous regular windows controls.

The best comparison I can think of right now is a level editor. The majority of the user interface is a standard window with panes that contain different controls. The scene is contained in another child window. When the user makes adjustments such as camera location, the scene responds accordingly.

So far, everything I've seen about cocos is geared around a single window. Is it possible to embed a scene into a child window as I've described?

Comment: Not quite.. But you can create some classes and implement your functionality. Basically it's one view.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom layer to your main scene using `Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()->addChild(...)` function